# Converting an array of objects to JSON in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, json

I have a `Person` class that has a `to_json` method defined:

```
class Person

  ...

  def to_json
    {
      last_name: @last_name,
      first_name: @first_name,
      gender: @gender,
      favorite_color: @favorite_color,
      date_of_birth: @date_of_birth
    }.to_json
  end
end
```

In another class I'm working with an array of `Person` objects.  How can I return this array as a long chunk of valid JSON data?  I've tried defining `to_json` in this new class like so:

```
class Directory

...

  def to_json
    @people.map do |person|
      person.to_json
    end.to_json
  end
end
```

But this is is giving me some sort of strange looking thing with a bunch of `"` and `\` characters scattered throughout the JSON data like this:

`["{\"last_name\":\"Dole\",\"first_name\":\"Bob\",\"gender\":\"M\",\"favorite_color\":\"Red\",\"date_of_birth\":\"01/02/1950\"}","{\"last_name\":\"Man\",\"first_name\":\"Bean\",\"gender\":\"M\",\"favorite_color\":\"Blue\",\"date_of_birth\":\"04/03/1951\"}","{\"last_name\":\"Man\",\"first_name\":\"Green\",\"gender\":\"F\",\"favorite_color\":\"Yellow\",\"date_of_birth\":\"02/15/1955\"}","{\"last_name\":\"Clinton\",\"first_name\":\"Bill\",\"gender\":\"M\",\"favorite_color\":\"Orange\",\"date_of_birth\":\"02/23/1960\"}"]`

whereas calling `to_json` on one `Person` is nicely formatted:

`{"last_name":"Bob","first_name":"Hob","gender":"M","favorite_color":"red","date_of_birth":"01/01/2000"}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is converting array of strings (json string), not array of hashes.

Instead of using `Person#to_json` in `Directory#to_json`, use `Person#to_hash` like following:

```
class Person
  def to_hash
    {
      last_name: @last_name,
      first_name: @first_name,
      gender: @gender,
      favorite_color: @favorite_color,
      date_of_birth: @date_of_birth
    }
  end

  def to_json
    to_hash.to_json
  end
end



class Directory
  def to_json
    @people.map do |person|
      person.to_hash
    end.to_json
  end
end
```